# BIDS Deploy Option -- What does it do, and why won't it work?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I just started using the BIDS plugin for Visual Studio, in conjunction with SSRS in integrated mode.  I created a Report Project, and when I was done creating a sample report I tried the deploy option under the Build menu.

Here are my relevant Build settings:

TargetReportFolder: http://intranet/Reports/Production Reports/

TargetServerURl: http://intranet/

I've tried variations on the above but continue to get various errors no matter what I try.

The above settings seem most likely to be correct to me, and generate the error: 
Client found response content type of '', but expected 'text/xml'.

I AM able to simply save the .rdl report file to the report folder mentioned above, and it works just fine.  So my PC does have permission to the location.
On a related note, what does 'deploy' do anyway vs just saving the file to its destination?

I have combed through dozens of posts by people with the same kind of problems but none of them seem to work for me.

Thanks

Comment: It could be that the TargetServerURL should be: http://intranet/Reports/Production Reports/ but in that case I get the error": Could not connect to the report server http://intranet/Reports/Production Reports/. Verify that the TargetServerUrl is valid and that you have the correct permissions to connect to the report server.

Comment: How about your TargetDataSourceFolder?  That needs to be a sharepoint path as well.

Comment: Yeah I had it set too.  Since I've seen dozens of other posts like this with no solutions, the only thing I can think of trying is re installing a different build of BIDS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple -- I downgraded the installation on my workstation from R2 to the original SQL Server 2008, which I had to dig around MS's site to find. Now it works perfectly.  (I failed to take note of the fact that our server is still on R1.)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the settings to:

TargetReportFolder: Production Reports

TargetServerURI: http://intranet/ReportServer

Note: http://intranet/Reports is Report Manager. You cannot deploy reports from BIDS to this location. HTH.

**Update:** Sorry. I missed the fact that you are running SSRS in Integrated Mode. I would recommend try removing the space in the folder name and use your previous settings.

Comment: Removing the space did not work.  I've been messing with this for hours.

Comment: For future reference, my settings are very similar to those listed in this article: http://whitepages.unlimitedviz.com/2010/05/deploying-reporting-services-reports-to-sharepoint-using-business-intelligence-development-visual-studio/  The only difference is that my root url is named intranet.  This situation is ridiculous, I see hundreds of others asking about the same problem with no solution.  At this point I'm just trying to figure out a workaround.